# Is there any way to implement Google actions on your own local Machine Learning Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, actions-on-google

For eg: The user types in something, the text goes to your ML model and then the model predicts and the answer will be the reply to the user.

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/) which will do the speech-to-text conversion and send you the text from the user. You can then apply whatever Natural Language Processing you want.

If by "local" you mean on a machine that doesn't have a public HTTPS URL, then you can look into [ngrok](https://ngrok.io/), which can provide a secure tunnel from a public HTTPS endpoint to your local machine.

Comment: Okay, great. And is there any way you can tunnel it to your local server, or is it required to use an external server?

Comment: If it has helped, upvoting and/or accepting the answer are always appreciated.